# Prisma create nested records throwing missing argument error

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, next.js, prisma

I have two tables `User` and `Account` in Postgresql

This is the `schema.prisma`

```
model account {
  id                            BigInt @id @default(autoincrement())
  name                          String @db.VarChar(32)
  owner_user_id                 BigInt
  status_id                     Int    @default(0) @db.SmallInt
  user                          user   @relation(fields: [owner_user_id], references: [id], onUpdate: Restrict, map: "owner")
  user_user_account_idToaccount user[] @relation("user_account_idToaccount")

  @@index([owner_user_id], map: "fki_owner")
}

model user {
  id                               BigInt    @id @default(autoincrement())
  nid                              String    @unique(map: "nid") @db.Char(21)
  first_name                       String    @db.VarChar(32)
  last_name                        String    @db.VarChar(32)
  account_id                       BigInt?
  email                            String    @unique(map: "email") @db.VarChar(64)
  password_hash                    String    @db.VarChar(128)
  status_id                        Int       @default(0) @db.SmallInt
  email_verified                   String    @default("0") @db.Bit(1)
  account                          account[]
  account_user_account_idToaccount account?  @relation("user_account_idToaccount", fields: [account_id], references: [id], onDelete: Restrict, onUpdate: Restrict, map: "account")

  @@index([account_id], map: "fki_account")
}
```

And I am executing this in Next.Js to create new user and account

```
const newUser = await prisma.user.create({
            data: {
                nid: nanoid(),
                first_name: 'John',
                last_name: 'Doe',
                status_id: 0,
                email_verified: 0,
                email,
                password_hash: `${salt}:${passwordHash}`,
                account: {
                    create: {
                        name: 'Jhonson',
                        status_id: 0,
                        owner_user_id: null
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```

But I am getting this error in console

```
PrismaClientValidationError: 
Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation:

{
  data: {
    nid: "ijaCe3YogZLIXCszb4OZA",
    first_name: "Valerie",
    last_name: "Tulle",
    status_id: 0,
    email_verified: 0,
    email: "ashraf.fahim75@gmail.com",
    password_hash: "91d44efc9f631a1c89ad1894f76c485d:92b442b342879fbcd36c4951cb484fcc77bdf1777a90d1c9c19fb2e8adf2e569220ae553a22c47f5b384082cd18a1b601c18a1941a8e44d5e5234b",
    account: {
      create: {
        name: "Auto",
        status_id: 0,
        owner_user_id: null
      }
    },
+   account_user_account_idToaccount: {
+     create: accountCreateWithoutUser_user_account_idToaccountInput | accountUncheckedCreateWithoutUser_user_aoaccountInput,
+     connectOrCreate: accountCreateOrConnectWithoutUser_user_account_idToaccountInput,
+     connect: accountWhereUniqueInput
+   }
  }
}

Argument `account_user_account_idToaccount` is missing.
...
```

Thanks,
New to Next.Js and Prisma